# is there a reason for doing this in an update set myfield = myfield?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm updating someone else's code that was written in php5 with mysql and I'm updating it to be compatible with php8

They have this a couple of times in UPDATE statements

```
UPDATE mytable
SET myfield = myfield, 
myotherfield = 2001
WHERE customerid = 20 AND ordernumber = 5001
```

Is there any reason to do this? I cannot see any rhyme or reason for setting a field to it's self in an update.

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be checked for in a trigger maybe?

Comment: I would guess that _sometimes_ it is setting `myfield = <expression>` depending on some conditions in the code. The programmer thought it was easier to set `myfield = myfield` when they didn't need it to change. What they should have done is run a different UPDATE statement with that assignment clause omitted.

Comment: @BillKarwin That usually shows up as something like `SET myfield = IF(condition, newvalue, myfield)` to keep it the same when the condition is false.

Comment: Sure, but regardless, it is true that setting a column to itself in an UPDATE is a noop. There might be some justification in the PHP code that calls this query, but there is no reason to do this with respect to the RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks. 

The DB has no trigger code.

Answer (score 1):

There's one case I can think of where it's useful.

If the column is a `TIMESTAMP` with the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` option, assigning it to itself will keep it from updating to the current time.

Comment: OK, that is good to know.  In my case it isn't time stamp.  Thanks.